# Excel VBA Select every other cell and paste it into another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I need to copy data from the 8th row into another sheet(sheet 2). I only need to copy every other cell, it should copy cell C8(first cell where the value is), E8, G8, I8 and so on from all the upto cell IK8.

Is there any way to do this? I have tried the step function in the for loop but its not working and only selecting one cell.It only pastes one value for cells H2:H130.

```
Sub Workplace()

Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim I As Long

LastRow = Worksheets("Questions").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For I = 8 To LastRow Step 3
Set rng = Worksheets("Questions").Range("C" & I)
rng.Copy
Next I
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2:H130").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment the column, not the row.

And move the paste *inside* the loop, though you need to increment the destination cell.

```
For i = 3 to 245 Step 2 ' column C to column IK
    Set rng = Worksheets("Questions").Cells(8, i)

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim dest as Range
        Set dest = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With

    rng.copy Destination:=dest
Next
```

Or better, just use `Union` to build up a range to copy and then copy in one step:

```
For i = 3 to 245 Step 2 ' column C to column IK
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = Worksheets("Questions").Cells(8, i)
    Else
        Set rng = Union(rng, Worksheets("Questions").Cells(8, i))
    End If
Next

rng.Copy
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

**EDIT**:

> "Is there a way to paste it in the first empty cell for Row H in sheet 1 instead of giving it a range?"

Yes, like the following:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

Comment: Instead of copying each cell one at a time in a loop user can also make union of those cells in your loop as `If rng Is Nothing Then
 Set rng = cell
 Else
 Set rng = Union(rng, cell)
 End If` and then paste it all at once to Sheet1!H2

Comment: Hello, is there a way to paste it in the first empty cell for Row H in sheet 1 instead of giving it a range?